# Azure Batch - Getting this error "Value":"%1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: azure, azure-batch, azure-batch-account

I'm trying to execute my python code in Azure Batch which pulls data from Adobe Analytics API. The code successfully runs in my local machine, not sure about the configuration in the pool in Az_Batch.

[AZ_Batch Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXk1G.png)

> {"errorCategory":0,"code":"CommandLaunchFailed","message":"Failed to
> launch the specified command
> line","details":[{"Name":"Message","Value":"%1 is not a valid Win32
> application."}]}

Could anyone please help me!!

[Az_Batch Libraries installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qACsr.png)
[Libraries installed locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqwJ4.png)

[Environment Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPoY3.png)
[Libraries Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tscqi.png)

Comment: Can you provide the commandline you are executing?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tscqi.png Please check this screenshot for the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Value":"%1 is not a valid Win32 application

- Please verify that the version of Python whether you are using  32 or 64 bit. If not, that might be the problem. if  you would have install 64 bit binaries for the library while running a 32-bit version of Python.
- Also  ***Update NumPy.***

  `'pip install numpy --upgrade`
- Use the pip method uninstall the pywin32 :

```py
      pip uninstall pywin32
```

The above command will remove the existing one which is by default for 32 bit computers. and again install pywin

```py
      pip install pywin32
```

- Check with path environment variables whether it is in correct path or is it in messed up, this could be one of the error you can faced.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 

I have re-installed it again but still receiving the same error. :(

Comment: Have you checked the path environment variables is in correct method and also check this [Document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory.md)

Comment: I have none in the Environment Settings, its empty. 

I have inserted the screenshots of the environment and the libs in my original post.

Comment: Issue fixed, i reinstalled all the libraries!!!

Thank you so much for the help